# client-side components based framework

Tags: javascriptmvc

Is there any   client side component based framework which gives me reusable components , like in java swings all I do is write code to assemble components to make  my window  and provide action listeners  to update component when user performs action , I go to server side only for data retrieval,update and all state is maintained at client side,I am looking for a framework which provides UI components and capability to override methods, instantiate data , provide action listeners etc.

Answer (score 0):

There's lot of choice out there from free open source to paid solution the most known:

- [Sencha ExtJS](http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/)
- [Dojo toolkit](http://dojotoolkit.org/)
- [Yui](http://yuilibrary.com/)
- [AlloyUI](http://alloyui.com/) based on YUI
- [Qooxdoo](http://qooxdoo.org/)

You can find more if you do some searchs